# Var $http not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build an Angularjs application and I'm having trouble with my controller.

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

  }).
  controller('indexCTRL', function ($scope) {
    $http.get('/api/frettir').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.posts = data;
    });

  });
```

But when I run it an error appears saying $http is not defined. What can I improve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to inject the `$http` service in the controllers you use it.  I like this very precise [inline syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) which will avoid problems if your code goes through minifiers.

```
controller('indexCTRL', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
     //...your code

    }
])
```

Comment: This is the better way to do it honestly. If you make it an array, latter on when you decide to minify it, you wont have to go back and do this to every single controller. I know this from experience :X lol

Answer (score 4):

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

  }).
  controller('indexCTRL', function ($scope, *$http*) {
    $http.get('/api/frettir').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.posts = data;
    });

  });
```

Comment: just needed to inject $http in the controller

Comment: I don't know like literally rite when i pressed add answer it had a -1 on it.

Comment: Yeah, we wrote answers at about the same time, I had 0 and you had -1... oh well.

Answer (score 2):

You should add it as a dependency to each controller that uses it:

```
controller('indexCTRL', function ($scope, $http) {
```