# Angularjs service undefined

Tags: angularjs

Was building out an angular application, but am getting error undefined with the service or factory. Specifically "can not read property of setName undefined".  I have went [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/V2YS090914-Understanding-AngularJS-Factory,-Service-and-Provider.html) to figure out my error. Even changed around my syntax figuring I maybe had something out of place but still throwing an undefined error.

Here is the controller:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular
    .module("app", [])
    .controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", mainCtrl]);

  function mainCtrl($scope, productService) {

    $scope.testService = productService.setName("Data Service");
  }
}());
```

Here is the service script:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular
    .module("app")
    .service("productService", function() {

      var serviceObj = {};
      serviceObj.name = '';
      serviceObj.setName = function(newName) {
        serviceObj.name = newName;
      };
      return serviceObj;
    });
}());
```

Originally, I had the service as :

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular
    .module("app")
    .service("productService", setName);

  function setName(newName) {
    var serviceObj = {};
    serviceObj.name = '';
    serviceObj.setName = function(newName) {
      serviceObj.name = newName;
    };
    return serviceObj;
  }
}());
```

Comment: Add product service to Controller declaration `['$scope', ` -> `['$scope', 'productService'`, you are missing injector adnotation for productService

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198596/var-http-not-defined/30198720#30198720) (if not duplicate) with built-in `$http` service instead of custom service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem recently and it seems to be that the function must be defined before the controller is created. I would recommend doing it the following way:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

//function
function mainCtrl($scope, productService) {
    $scope.testService = productService.setName("Data Service");
} 

//Controller and Module Init
angular
    .module("app", [])        
    .controller("mainCtrl", mainCtrl);  

//Inject requirements (This is needed for Minification) 
mainCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "productService"];

}());
```

Comment: This works although I am curious as to why it works and will continue looking

Comment: When you find out, let me know. This problem bugged me before as I believed order wasn't important in JS (or any functional program) but it must be to do with one of the Angular Elves.